# Java Android - Will Decompiling and Compiling end successfully?

Tags: java, android, decompiling

I want to get an app (apk file), decompile it, add a code which will send area to my server. The question: will it be ok? Decompiling+adding custom code+compiling won't occur on work and internal logic? So, will the app work as expected after those steps?

Comment: "will it be ok?" -- ask your attorney.

Comment: From technical side :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually it works, but not always.  When this doesn't work, the decompiler doesn't get it right, but if you can guess what the code should be, you can get it to work.

Comment: Results are generally less favorable when decompiling code that was converted from Android format.  The conversion tools often emit nasty exception handler tables with overlapping handler ranges, which most decompilers will barf on.  And then there's obfuscation.